# How to optimize T-SQL stored procedure to search thru a source table and insert into a destination table for new records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, stored-procedures

I created the below stored procedure to pull data from a source table and insert only "new records" into a destination table. I need to run this every minute. The challenge is that the table stores "images"  with over 2 million rows.

When I run the stored procedure it is still running over 1 hour and 22 minutes. I've already moved all images over to this table so there are no new images to pull over so I'm assuming it's still reading the table for new records. The job is not being blocked and is still runnable.

Is there any way to optimize this stored procedure so that it pulls only new records. My goal would be to optimize so that we can run this on a re-occuring schedule. The business requirements are to run this every minute, but based on the current outcome that is not possible.

I've included the source and target table schema so you can see all columns that I have to work with. I am not sure if I can use the created_date in the source table to filter the data so it doesn't look thru all the data. There is also an identity column (`acc_image_id`) in the source table. I'm not sure how I should modify the stored procedure to pull data more quickly based on the `max(identity)`.

FYI, I can add columns to the target table if it makes sense to add a column to help filter this data further so that it only looks for recent images.

Source table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[acc_image]
(
    [acc_image_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [acc_id] [int] NULL,
    [image_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [data_format] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [label] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [image_width] [smallint] NULL,
    [image_height] [smallint] NULL,
    [image_color_depth] [tinyint] NULL,
    [image_thumbnail] [image] NOT NULL,
    [data] [image] NOT NULL,
    [notes] [text] NULL,
    [acc_specimen_id] [int] NULL,
    [acc_slide_id] [int] NULL,
    [include_in_report] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [include_in_internet] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [created_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [row_version] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [report_section_number] [smallint] NULL,
    [external_notes] [text] NULL,
    [source_filename] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [page_count] [int] NOT NULL,
    [include_as_attachment] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [sort_order] [smallint] NULL,
    [acc_parent_image_id] [int] NULL,
    [created_by_id] [int] NULL,
    [annotation] [text] NULL,
    [specimen_results_enabled] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [dis_imageserver_id] [int] NULL,
    [external_slide_image_id] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [external_report_image_id] [varchar](80) NULL,
)
```

Here is the target table schema. I have an `inserted_date` that I don't know if I can use to optimize:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[acc_image]
(
    [acc_image_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [acc_id] [int] NULL,
    [image_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [data_format] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [label] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [image_width] [int] NULL,
    [image_height] [int] NULL,
    [image_color_depth] [tinyint] NULL,
    [image_thumbnail] [image] NOT NULL,
    [data] [image] NOT NULL,
    [image_guid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [created_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [row_version] [varbinary](12) NOT NULL,
    [sort_order] [int] NULL,
    [insert_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [updated_date] [datetime] NULL,
)
```

Here's the stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_image]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RecCt AS int = 0

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO connect_onprem.dbo.acc_image (acc_image_id, acc_id, image_type_id,    
                                                  data_format, label, description, 
                                                  image_width, image_height, 
                                                  image_color_depth, image_thumbnail, 
                                                  data, created_date, row_version, sort_order)
        SELECT 
            src.acc_image_id, a.id, src.image_type_id, 
            src.data_format, src.label, src.description, 
            src.image_width, src.image_height,
            src.image_color_depth, src.image_thumbnail,
            src.data, src.created_date, src.row_version, src.sort_order
        FROM 
            [ARKPPTEST\POWERPATHTEST].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].accession_2 a 
        INNER JOIN 
            [ARKPPTEST\POWERPATHTEST].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_specimen s ON a.primary_specimen_id = s.id
        INNER JOIN 
            [ARKPPTEST\POWERPATHTEST].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_slide ass ON s.id = ass.acc_specimen_id
        --source table      
        INNER JOIN 
            [ARKPPTEST\POWERPATHTEST].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_image src ON ass.id = src.acc_slide_id
    
        --target table
        LEFT JOIN 
            connect_onprem.dbo.acc_image tgt ON src.acc_image_id = tgt.acc_image_id
        WHERE 
            tgt.acc_image_id IS NULL
            AND a.acc_type_id <> 134
            AND a.status_final = 'Y'
        ORDER BY 
            acc_image_id
    
    SET @RecCt = @@ROWCOUNT

    IF @RecCt > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO connect_onprem.dbo.ErrorLog (UserName, ErrorNumber, ErrorState, 
                        ErrorSeverity, ErrorLine,  ErrorProcedure, ErrorMsg, ErrorDateTime)
        Values ('RecTrack', @RecCt, 0, 0, 0, 'get_image', 
                            'connect_onprem.dbo.acc_image Inserted Records', GETDATE());
    END


END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
INSERT INTO  connect_onprem.dbo.ErrorLog (UserName, ErrorNumber, ErrorState, ErrorSeverity, 
                  ErrorLine, ErrorProcedure,  ErrorMsg, ErrorDateTime)
VALUES (SUSER_SNAME(), ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_LINE(), 
            ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), GETDATE());
    END CATCH
END
```

**Goal**: optimize this to run as fast as possible; to read the source table and insert "new" records into the target table using a linked server running across the network.

Right now, the stored procedure is running over 1 hour and 22 minutes.  I need to somehow change this to be able to run at the minimum every 1 minute (if possible).

Comment: FYI the `text` and `image` datatypes have been deprecated since **2005**, why are you still using them? If also question a table that has 4 LOB data types, and 3 of them string-based; are those 3 columns *really* likely to have over 8,000 characters each?

Comment: Performance questions require details of the tables, indexes and constraints involved, as well as the actual execution plan (Paste The Plan). What is the reason you are using 4-part naming?

Comment: I didn't even spot the 4 part naming... If this is a linked server query, parsing all those up to 2GB columns to the calling server will be *awful* for performance.

Comment: @Thom A  It's a vendor app that is our LIMS system.  we don't control how they build it out.

Comment: @Stu, I'm pulling data from a linked server which is why you see the 4 part naming convention.  I should be more consistent.  I'll post the execution plan, indexes and constrings, what other details about the table are you looking for?

Comment: @ThomA  it is a linked server and I'm not sure how to get around other than moving the database to our production server which is a NO NO according to the vendor.  They've already said they won't support us if it's not a dedicated sql server.

Comment: It would be far better to run this query in a procedure on the source server and reference via linked server; you could also look at the `remote` join hint.

Comment: Yet they're using unsupported data types? This feels like a vendor that has no idea what they are doing.

Comment: I was thinking about taking out the joins and just moving over any changes.  If I did that based off max(id) would that be faster?

Comment: Separately I'd question the design of storing images in the database; I've worked on databases that stored binary file data and whilst yes you can do it, it never works well and does not scale.  Files belong in the file system, clue's in the name :)

Comment: Honestly, the more information we get here, the more I think that this is *not* a vendor you should be using any more... Having multiple LOBs in a single table, using deprecated data types, storing files in the database, won't support a client that uses their server for other things... I assume they'd drop support if you set up a read only replica of the database too..?

Comment: Since you have a [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) column (`row_version`, data type `timestamp` aka `rowversion`) in the source table, you should be able to use it to identify any rows that have been inserted or updated since the last pass of your stored procedure. Just pick up any rows that have a larger `row_verion` value than the maximum value you have already processed. (It won't help if deleted rows also need to be synchronized between tables.) Indexing it in the source table should optimize performance.

Comment: Oh yeah, your vendor gets extra credit from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks): "The **timestamp** syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature."

Comment: @dba_gal - Regarding your `max(id)` question, I think that would only work if you know that there would be no gaps or stragglers with id values less than the latest. The condition `a.status_final = 'Y'` might cause issues, since I expect some statuses achieve final status faster than others. If you can formulate a query that can select `min(id)` where any kay data may have been added or changed on the remote server side, that might give you a usable lower limit for the primary data retrieval.

Comment: I think I can remove the where criteria and just bring over all new records based on max(id).  I think there may be better ways of getting max(id) since it's an identity.   I'm thinking if I do it that way, I won't have gaps in the ID field.  thoughts?

Comment: @dba_gal - Even if you eliminate the status condition, I would still be cautious about using a `max(id)` approach. Even though `identity` columns will have sequentially assigned numbers, multiple simultaneous transactions might commit the inserts out of order and there is a ***very slight*** chance that you might skip an uncommitted row. Adding a bit of overlap by using something like `max(id) - overlap_factor` might be enough to eliminate any remaining chance of leaving a row behind, but that seems klugy. Also consider whether retrieved data might change before the status becomes final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the remote part of the query is retrieving and transferring all selected data (including the presumably large `data` and `image_thumbnail` values) from the remote database before checking locally for the existence of a local copy.

I would assume that once the initial load is complete, most of the retrieved data will be discarded as duplicate.  For example, you might have one million records in your remote source, but only one thousand need to be inserted as new rows to your target table.

The solution may be to initially just select ID values into a temp table (or table variable) and then use that in a second query to actually select and insert the final data. retrieving one million ID values to be checked up front should be immensely faster than retrieving one million complete rows. Later, after the IDs have been filtered, retrieving just those one thousand rows may complete relatively fast.

Something like:

```
    DECLARE @Selected_Ids TABLE(acc_image_id int not null)

    -- Pre-select IDs
    INSERT INTO @Selected_Ids(acc_image_id)
    SELECT
        src.acc_image_id
    FROM [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].accession_2 a 
    INNER JOIN [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_specimen s ON 
                                    a.primary_specimen_id = s.id
    INNER JOIN [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_slide ass ON  
                                    s.id = ass.acc_specimen_id
           --source table       
          INNER JOIN [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_image src  on   
                                    ass.id = src.acc_slide_id
    
          --target table
          LEFT JOIN connect_onprem.dbo.acc_image tgt  ON src.acc_image_id = tgt.acc_image_id
    WHERE tgt.acc_image_id is null 
    AND a.acc_type_id <> 134
    AND a.status_final = 'Y'
    -- order by acc_image_id
    
    -- Main select
    INSERT INTO connect_onprem.dbo.acc_image(acc_image_id, acc_id, image_type_id,    
data_format, label, description, image_width, image_height, image_color_depth, image_thumbnail, 
data, created_date, row_version, sort_order)
    SELECT 
    src.acc_image_id, 
    a.id, 
    src.image_type_id, 
    src.data_format, 
    src.label, 
    src.description, 
    src.image_width,
    src.image_height,
    src.image_color_depth,
    src.image_thumbnail,
    src.data,
    src.created_date,
    src.row_version,
    src.sort_order

    FROM [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].accession_2 a 
    INNER JOIN [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_specimen s ON 
                                    a.primary_specimen_id = s.id
    INNER JOIN [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_slide ass ON  
                                    s.id = ass.acc_specimen_id
    INNER JOIN [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_image src  on   
                                    ass.id = src.acc_slide_id
    WHERE src.acc_image_id IN (SELECT sel.acc_image_id FROM @Selected_Ids sel)
    --order by src.acc_image_id
```

It appears that you can eliminate several joins from the second query by saving the accession ID during the preselect. Since all of the filters have already been applied, and the rest of the data comes from the acc_image table, the other tables need not be referenced.

```
    DECLARE @Selected_Ids TABLE(acc_image_id int not null, acc_id int not null)

    -- Pre-select IDs
    INSERT INTO @Selected_Ids(acc_image_id, acc_id)
    SELECT
        src.acc_image_id,
        a.id
    FROM [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].accession_2 a 
    INNER JOIN [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_specimen s ON 
                                    a.primary_specimen_id = s.id
    INNER JOIN [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_slide ass ON  
                                    s.id = ass.acc_specimen_id
           --source table       
          INNER JOIN [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_image src  on   
                                    ass.id = src.acc_slide_id
    
          --target table
          LEFT JOIN connect_onprem.dbo.acc_image tgt  ON src.acc_image_id = tgt.acc_image_id
    WHERE tgt.acc_image_id is null 
    AND a.acc_type_id <> 134
    AND a.status_final = 'Y'
    -- order by acc_image_id
    
    -- Main select
    INSERT INTO connect_onprem.dbo.acc_image(acc_image_id, acc_id, image_type_id,    
data_format, label, description, image_width, image_height, image_color_depth, image_thumbnail, 
data, created_date, row_version, sort_order)
    SELECT 
    src.acc_image_id, 
    sel.acc_id,
    src.image_type_id, 
    src.data_format, 
    src.label, 
    src.description, 
    src.image_width,
    src.image_height,
    src.image_color_depth,
    src.image_thumbnail,
    src.data,
    src.created_date,
    src.row_version,
    src.sort_order

    FROM @Selected_Ids sel
    INNER JOIN [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_image src on   
                                    sel.acc_image_id = src.acc_image_id
    --order by src.acc_image_id
```

The query engine might perform a loop join to retrieve one remote `acc_image` row at a time or it might send a list of all preselected ids to the remote server for a batch retrieval. You should run performance tests on both and examine the resulting execution plans.

You might even try the following hybrid of the above in the second query:

```
    ...
    FROM [RemoteServer].[Powerpath_Test].[dbo].acc_image src
    INNER JOIN @Selected_Ids sel on
                                    src.acc_image_id = sel.acc_image_id
    WHERE src.acc_image_id IN (SELECT sel1.acc_image_id FROM @Selected_Ids sel1)
```

(Note that I commented out the `order by`, as I believe it to be unnecessary.)

Comment: thank you!  You are awesome!  I'll let you know how this works out, but I think this will solve the issue.

Comment: Here is the time for the 1st query:   SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1422 ms,  elapsed time = 2080 ms.  Here is the time for the 2nd query: SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1375 ms,  elapsed time = 2073 ms.  For the parts of this that are doing the most work.

Comment: My last question is becuase there is no index for the table variable this is doing a table scan.  There could be 100's of rows moved at at time NOT 1000's of rows.  Is it worthwhile to change the table variable to an actual table to be able to add indexes?  That means I'd have to add a custom table to our vendor app which they will scream about.

Comment: @T N  Thank you!  My job is running this stored procedure as well as 6 others that load data in around 1 minute and 9 sec's.  This is where i need it  it!  HUGE improvement, Thank you soo much!

Comment: Glad it helped. Regarding a table variable vs an indexed temp table, I do not believe it should make much difference. If there are only a few hundred selected IDs, you are only talking about a few KB of data. and the intheent is that would all be processed in one pass in the second query. It doesn't hurt to experiment though. You could even define a P in t table variable with `DECLARE @Selected_Ids TABLE(acc_image_id int not null primary key)`. The important think is to have suitable indexes in the remote database, but the vendor should have taken care of that for typical uses.